# Random crashes when training with multiple threads on Tensorflow

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, parallel-processing

#### Problem

The following script randomly crashes (i.e., sometimes crashes and produces this traceback, most of the times it does not). The script trains the MNIST softmax model in parallel leveraging several threads.

You can easily reproduce the crash by running `for ((n=0;n<100;n++)); do python mnist_softmax_parallel_issue.py; done`

*Traceback*

```
external/eigen_archive/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorBroadcasting.h:125: Eigen::TensorEvaluator<const Eigen::TensorBroadcastingOp<Broadcast, XprType>, Device>::T
ensorEvaluator(const XprType&, const Device&) [with Broadcast = const Eigen::IndexList<Eigen::type2index<1l>, int>; ArgType = const Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float, 2, 1, long
 int>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer>; Device = Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice; Eigen::TensorEvaluator<const Eigen::TensorBroadcastingOp<Broadcast, XprType>, Device>::XprType = Eigen::TensorBroadcastingOp<const Eigen::IndexList<Eigen::type2index<1l>, int>, const Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float, 2, 1, long int>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> >]: Assertion input_dims[i] > $' failed.
```

#### Source code

*mnist_softmax_device_issue.py*

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import argparse
import sys

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

import tensorflow as tf
import threading
import numpy as np
import json
import os
import time

FLAGS = None

INTER_OP_PARALLELISM = 76
INTRA_OP_PARALLELISM = 1
BATCH_SIZE = 100
ITERATIONS = 1000
TRAINING_THREADS = 46

threads = [None] * TRAINING_THREADS

def train_function(thread_idx, mnist, sess, train_step, x, y_, y):
  iterations = int(ITERATIONS/TRAINING_THREADS)
  for i in range(iterations):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

def main(_):
  mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir, one_hot=True)

  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
  W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
  b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
  y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b

  y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

  cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
      tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))
  train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5, use_locking=True).minimize(cross_entropy)

  sess = tf.InteractiveSession(config=tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads = INTRA_OP_PARALLELISM, inter_op_parallelism_threads= INTER_OP_PARALLELISM))
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

  for i in range(TRAINING_THREADS):
      threads[i] = threading.Thread(target=train_function, args=[i, mnist, sess, train_step, x, y_, y])

  for thread in threads:
      thread.start()
  for thread in threads:
      thread.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('--data_dir', type=str, default='mnist-data',
                      help='Directory for storing input data')
  FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
  tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
```

#### System information

- **OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04)**:  Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
- **TensorFlow installed from (source or binary)**: source
- **TensorFlow version (use command below)**: 1.3.0-rc2
- **Python version**:  2.7.12
- **Bazel version (if compiling from source)**: 0.4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mnist.train.next_batch()` is not thread safe. Thereafter, `batch_xs` and `batch_ys` can get matrixes of shape `(0, 784)` and `(0, 10)`, respectively.

The aforementioned assert is triggered when passing these matrixes with zero lines.